# Как корректно отобразить объект на странице

Tags: javascript

Проблема такая, ко мне на страницу заходят пользователь(новая страница - новый пользователь), все они заносятся в объект объектов с полями name и id, если мы откроем 1 страницу пользователь запишется корректно, если откроем вторую, то на второй странице будет все хорошо(допустим andrey, john), а на первой будет andrey, andrey, john. и так каждая последующая страница имеет дубликаты, как можно выводить без них?
Вот код:

```
const addUserToModalWindow = () => {
    const contentWindow = document.querySelector(".usersList");
    socket.on('users', (users) => {
        for (let user of Object.values(users)) {
            contentWindow.innerHTML += `<div>• ${user.name}</div>`;
        }
    });
};
```

Вот как выглядит на сайте и хранится на сервере объект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас текст постоянно дописывается в конец

```
contentWindow.innerHTML +=
```

Чтобы не дублировать вывод достаточно либо очищать элемент перед циклом вывода:

```
contentWindow.innerHTML = '';
for (let user of Object.values(users)) {
```

либо добавить событие добавления пользователя в котором получать только нового добавленного пользователя.

Comment: Очищать не вариант, потому что тогда при заходе на сервер с второй страницы не будет показан человек, который сидит с первой

Comment: @ВикторияМот, если бы это было так, то у тебя не дублировались бы люди в выводе. Так как они дублируются, очевидно в списке `users` все присутствующие на данный момент